# Hot water heater vent goes through bedroom making it hot

Tags: insulation, water-heater, venting

Our home was built in the 1950’s. The hot water heater is located in the basement and is directly beneath a bedroom. The hot water heater vent runs through that bedroom closet making that bedroom hot in the summer. The vent pipe is pretty warm to the touch. What can I do about it? Can it be insulated? Does it need a new vent pipe?

Comment: How large a basement is this? What is the climate? Does the basement get cold in winter? Consider changing the water heater to an electric heat pump water heater.

Comment: Usually vents for heaters need to go by local regulations.  They will tell you what can be done.  If the heater is older(10 to 20 years), the possibility of it needing to be replaced(maybe moved) soon, goes way up.

Answer (score 1):

Either:

1. replace with a twin wall insulated pipe or
2. box it in with a layer of insulation,

Either will need to surface pipe and running temperatures checked.

ALSo, local regulations must be checked.

Comment: Would adding a vent fan help?